# functions saved in library not working

Tags: python

when i use random they are giving me attribute randint is not assigned to random( i imported random) i tried fixing it but got myself into more trouble, all the saved functions in python are not working like turtle this is what they are giving me on the terminal (fyi i'm working on mac)
Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "dotgrid.py", line 1, in 
>       import turtle
>     File "/Users/jamilaldani/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/turtle.py", line 111, in 
>       import inspect
>     File "/Users/jamilaldani/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 40, in 
>       import linecache
>     File "/Users/jamilaldani/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/linecache.py", line 11, in 
>       import tokenize
>     File "/Users/jamilaldani/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/tokenize.py", line 41, in 
>       **all** = token.**all** + ["COMMENT", "tokenize", "detect_encoding",
>   AttributeError: module 'token' has no attribute '**all**'

Comment: what other python files do you have in your local directory besides `dotgrid.py`, check your `PYTHONPATH`, are any of the files named `token.py` or similarly named that might conflict with `built-in` python library files.

Comment: yes  i have a file named token.py but why will it conflict with builtin python library files and what can i do to go back to normal?

Comment: Ok jus rename your `token.py` to another name, anything like `myscript.py` and it will clear the error. The reason it conflicts with the python built-in file is because they both are on your `PYTHONPATH` and the file names must be unique, just change the file to another name that python doesn't already have.

Comment: Thanks a lot it finally worked